# how to disable global variable from lib.dom.d.ts?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

I'm using Visual studio code to develop nodeJS apps and already have an eslint configuration to lint undeclared variables.

But in recent VSCode versions, some undeclared variable are not linted anymore. like `event`, `name`, `crypto`, ...

When reaching the variable definition, it is actually declared in the file `Microsoft VS Code Insiders\resources\app\extensions\node_modules\typescript\lib\lib.dom.d.ts`

I can't see any reason why those variables should be declared globally for nodeJS apps. How can I disable the global definition of thoses variables?

Comment: related? https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14306 and https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/37053

Answer (score 15):

From the docs for [`tsconfig.json compilerOptions.lib`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#lib):

> TypeScript includes a default set of type definitions for built-in JS APIs (like `Math`), ***as well as type definitions for things found in browser environments (like `document`)***.

You can exclude dom suggestions by setting `"lib": ["es6"]` (or whichever ECMA Script standard API version you want to be able to use) in a [`jsconfig.json`](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages/javascript#_javascript-projects-jsconfigjson):

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES6",
        "lib": ["es6"]
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "**/node_modules/*"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you! that seems to work except that eslint is not yet able to lint it as a missing definition. VSC Intellisence doesnt offered me `event` when beginning to write `ev...`: good! After finishing to write `event`, when I reach for example for `event` definition (ctrl + click), `lib.dom.d.ts` is not targetted anymore: good! but VSC recognizes now `event` as `any`: too bad

Comment: @DamienLeroux One workaround is to just copy all the contents of the `lib.dom.d.ts` file into a local/in-project copy, with your desired changes applied. (obvious workaround, but thought I'd mention it)

Comment: At the time of writing this is not entirely correct. [Triple slash directives](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/triple-slash-directives.html) can have the effect that `"dom"` gets included although the user has excluded it in their `tsconfig.json`, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63109147/1804173). However, that might just be a TypeScript bug, raised [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/43990).

Comment: Correction: I was referring to the "full" TypeScript case. I wasn't aware that plain JS uses `.d.ts` files as well.