# Why am I still getting types from lib.dom.d.ts when I have overridden the lib property in my tsconfig to omit the dom lib?

Tags: typescript

I'm having an issue where I'm trying to compile a TypeScript Node project without DOM types, but TypeScript keeps including the DOM types.  Here is my `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "lib": [
            "ES6"
        ],
        "target": "es6",
        "module": "commonjs",
        
        "declaration": true,
        "outDir": "./dist",
        "rootDir": "./src",
        "strict": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
    }
}
```

As you can see, I am using `"lib": ["ES6"]` which is suppose to get rid of the DOM types. Using `tsc --showconfig` I can verify that this is the config that I am using. However, VSCode's IntelliSense allows me to write out types for the HTML elements, and, on compilation, I get an error talking specifically about a clash with a type in `lib.dom.d.ts`, even though the `tsconfig` is suppose to exclude them (the ellipses are my own):

```
node_modules/@types/webgl2/index.d.ts:582:13 - error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'WebGL2RenderingContext' must be of type (...), but here has type (...).

582 declare var WebGL2RenderingContext: {
                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  C:/Users/username/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts:16316:13
    16316 declare var WebGL2RenderingContext: {
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    'WebGL2RenderingContext' was also declared here.
```

How can the two definitions of `WebGL2RenderingContext` clash if I am excluding DOM types in my `tsconfig`?

Answer (score 13):

We were running into the same problem. While it may be a different culprit in your case, here is how you could narrow it down:

Create an empty project, take your `tsconfig.json` and use a minimal code snippet that works only if `lib.dom.d.ts` is in scope like:

```
// This works in a browser, but should fail to compile for nodejs, because in
// nodejs, and explicit import is needed.
const time = performance.now();
```

If this fails to compile you know that your `tsconfig.json` is good in general.

Now slowly bring in third partly dependencies, i.e., start npm-installing the dependencies that you had in your "broken" project one-by-one, until you reach the point were the compilation suddenly passes.

In our case the problematic dependency was `@types/supertest`, which in turn had pulled in `@types/superagent`. The problem with `@types/superagent` is that it contains the [triple slash directive](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/triple-slash-directives.html):

```
/// <reference lib="dom" />
```

This seems to have the effect that `lib.dom.d.ts` gets included into the compilation, effectively overriding the `"lib": ["ES6"]` you have in your `tsconfig.json`.

Perhaps you can also find the culprit more quickly by specifically looking for that line in your dependencies.

I still don't have a good answer though how to deal with the problem. Clearly installing a dependency should not result in letting the compilation silently pass on cases that should be a compilation error in a non-browser context. I have opened an [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/43990) on the TypeScript repo to see if this can be fixed, and there's another [issue](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/41425) opened for `@types/superagent`.

Comment: Note also related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62087887/1804173).

Comment: You can avoid doing this dependency-by-dependency by using [`explainFiles`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#explainFiles)

Comment: Adding `"lib": ["ESNext"]` helped me in my case, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

All `@types` packages from your `package.json` are included by default in the project when the `"types"` compiler option isn't specified.

In this case the error message shows you have `@types/webgl2` installed, and you did not specify which types to include, so it included all types by default.

If you'd like to exclude all types you'd set the following in `tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
  // ...

  "compilerOptions" : {
    // ...

    "types": [],

    // ...
  }
}
```

And as always with Typescript, after making config changes make sure to reboot the Language Server using the `"Restart Typescript Server"` command (press `F1` in VSCode).

Comment: what if I want to include the `@types` packages I've installed but still ignore the DOM types?

Answer (score -1):

> Using TypeScript without DOM types (for node)

Your tsconfig is the right way to do this. i.e.

```
   "lib": [
        "ES6"
    ],
```

## Why you are getting the error

You most likely have *another* tsconfig.json in your workspace that is being picked up by vscode.

Comment: I said in the question that `tsc --showconfig` shows the config that I am using. IE, if it was another `tsconfig`, a different one would show up there.

Comment: I am experiencing the same problem with `"lib": ["esnext"]`